# Parse huge logger files in directory

Tags: java, logging

I have list of folders which has list of all log files stored in zip format.  I need to read all the folders and each zip folder which contains one log file inside . i need to get some key  i.e for example "Get-Id" from each files and find the count on same.

Can someone help me with this as there are many files and how to parse each file one by one from zip content .And also how to parse using which method in Java?

Comment: You can use java's ZipInputStream but I would be looking for a shell script solution

Comment: @Bohemian  how to do you parse each line by line for those keyword?

Comment: can you tell me how to do this in shell script?

Comment: If you're using linux, there's [zgrep](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm), which isn't particularly fast, but you'll have something working in a few minute.

Comment: Can you provide me the syntax as i have not written anything in unix so far.. iam trying something like this . I go inside the particular folder where there are multiple zip files . this is the command :$ zgrep -R --include=*.gz -H "GET ID". But it says -R not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to do the same in Unix. The commands i used are 
$ find ./ -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -i "GET ID" | wc –l

It worked fine and thanks for all the inputs so far.